# SQL Server Access Modifiers for a function

Tags: sql-server, access-modifiers

I have a function in my database on a SQL Server 2008 R2 which calls another function based on the first parameter.

Like this:

> SELECT dbo.usp_Function1('customerX', ...)

This calls a different function *usp_Function1CustomerX*, which is specific to a customer.

The thing is, I don't want anyone to be able to call *usp_Function1CustomerX* from outside the database.

More precise: I don't want this function to be called from code in visual studio or any OR-mapper. It would be like having an (c# term) internal access modifier for my function in the SQL Server.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Robert

EDIT Changed example from stored procedure to function

Comment: Don't you mean stored procedure? Not function. Quite different in SQL Server

Comment: You are right, they are different. I do need it for both. I recon my example may lead to some confusion

Answer (score 0):

*solution 1*

each Sp has permission section which you can modify to fit.

*solution 2*

you can add a param to the func which it will be checked inside.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the permissions properties for the function: I can specify a database role (like public, guest, or specific user) and set permission like alter, control ... et c. How would I be able to change the visibility to the outside?

Solution2: Do you suggest some kind of "magic" value in a specific parameter?